# Overflowing images that don't conform to aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a basic thumbnail list which can contain images of varying aspect ratios as illustrated in this fiddle:

### [Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/v6q426bp/)

The problem is - it looks a bit untidy due to the mishmash of aspect ratios.

Ideally I would like the images that don't conform to a specific aspect ratio to stay centered and overflow gracefully based on their shortest edge.

I've managed to get it to work for tall images but not wide ones as demonstrated in this fiddle:

### [Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/v6q426bp/1/)

Here is the markup and CSS:

## CSS

```
.galleryArea {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    display:flex;
    padding: 10px;
}
.galleryArea .imageWrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: calc(10% - 2px);
    padding-top: 8%;
    margin: 0 1px;
}
.galleryArea .imagePosition {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.galleryArea .imagePosition img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

## HTML

```
<div class="galleryArea">
    <div class="imageWrapper">
        <div class="imagePosition">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="imageWrapper">
        <div class="imagePosition">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="imageWrapper">
        <div class="imagePosition">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/150x400">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="imageWrapper">
        <div class="imagePosition">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="imageWrapper">
        <div class="imagePosition">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x100">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="imageWrapper">
        <div class="imagePosition">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="imageWrapper">
        <div class="imagePosition">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="imageWrapper">
        <div class="imagePosition">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="imageWrapper">
        <div class="imagePosition">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="imageWrapper">
        <div class="imagePosition">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ideally this would be a pure CSS solution, but if it's impossible I don't mind using JS(jQuery) to achieve the result.

Many thanks

Chris

---

## Edit

To better illustrate my intentions, here is an example showing it working using jQuery. Is this achievable using `CSS` only?

### [Demo 3](http://jsfiddle.net/v6q426bp/8/)

Comment: Note that your Demo 2 works in Chrome and IE but not in Firefox.  I suspect some aspect of flex is not fully supported yet.

Comment: Sorry I should have stipulated. This only needs to work in IE 11 as it is for a WinJS application written in HTML and CSS.

Comment: height can be specified for each cell?

Comment: is this you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/v6q426bp/3/

Comment: @Ehtesham Each cell should be the same height and width and the image should fill it based on its shortest dimension.

Here is an example of it kind of working using jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/v6q426bp/6/

Comment: Your jQuery solution is the way to go.  The CSS positioning that is needed depends on the aspect ratio of the image.  CSS cannot detect the aspect ratio of an image so you need JavaScript/jQuery to detect the dimensions/aspect-ratio which then allows you to apply the appropriate formatting, which is essentially what you did.

Answer (score 0):

You can letterbox the images with just CSS using `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` and width just an `overflow:hidden` on `.imagePosition` images will be center aligned vertically and horizontally.

```
.galleryArea .imagePosition img {
    width: auto;
    max-width: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: block;
}
```

Example fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/v6q426bp/11/

You can also add either `height:100%` or `width:100%` to the image to restrict the layout even more.

With `height:100%` - Same as the link above or below with a 12 (unable to add more then 2 links)

Width `width:100%` - http://jsfiddle.net/v6q426bp/13/